# Annoying vim behavior in visual mode

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following three lines and cursor is where ▐ is:

```
1. This is a slightly longer line.▐I want to delete this and the next line.
2. This is a shorter line
3. This is the third line
```

I want to delete the rest of the line from the cursor and line 2, so I do `vjd`, but that leaves my text like:

```
# This is a slightly longer line.# This is the third line
```

This is because when selecting text in visual mode, vim selects an additional virtual character at the end of the line. I've played around with `virtualedit` but that didn't seem to help.

Any clues on how I can get the original behavior that I wanted?

Comment: I would just do `vjhd`

Comment: With the same 4 keystrokes `Djdd`

Comment: There is also `vjg_d` wich will work however long the second line is -- as Meninx solution does.

Comment: instead of `g_` why not using `$` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try three keystrokes - sh-d, sh-j, sh-d

shift-d (delete to end-of-line)

shift-j (merge next line with this)

shift-d (delete the merged, i.e., second line

That will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because if you don't have virtualedit set, `vjd` will delete everything including the new line character. So you just have to do `vjhd` instead, to keep the new line intact.

Otherwise with `virtualedit=all`, I don't face this problem.